# Problem with \and within \hypersetup{pdfauthor=...}

Tags: macros, hyperref, titles

I use a custom macro to set the author of both my document and its metadata. It had worked fine until I started writing a document with a colleague.

This is the code:

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    PDF INFO
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand*{\mytitle}{Equacions diferencials}
\newcommand*{\myauthor}{Alfredo Hernández \and John Smith} 
\newcommand*{\myuni}{Universitat Autònoma de Barcelona, Departament de Física}
\newcommand*{\mydate}{\normalsize 2013-2014}

\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor={\myauthor}, pdftitle={\mytitle}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    TITLE SECTION AND DOCUMENT BEGINNING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\horrule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}
\title{
    \normalfont
    \small \scshape{\myuni} \\ [25pt] 
    \horrule{0.5pt} \\[0.4cm]
    \huge \mytitle \\
    \horrule{2pt} \\[0.5cm]
}
\author{\myauthor}
\date{\mydate}

\begin{document}
```

As I understand it, the command `\and` is the proper way to set more than one authors. The problem is that `hypersetup` crashes when trying to write the metadata (of course, if I delete \and, the document renders perfectly).

Do you know any workaround to keep using \myauthor command in the metadata and the title itself?

---

**SOLUTIONS THAT MAY WORK:**

1. I have tried using `&` between the authors, but ShareLatex tells me that `\cr` is better. However, I don't know what the `\cr` command does and I want to avoid using code I don't know, also I don't even know if that is a proper solution in terms of coding.
2. I think that using \author1 and \author2 could solve my problem, (`\author{\author1 \and \author2}`; `\hypersetup{pdfauthor={\author1 , \author2}`), but again, I don't think this is the best solution.

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Okay, I'll have that in mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two approaches:

1. Add `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\and{and }}` after loading `hyperref`
2. Define two different strings for TeX and for PDF

   ```
   \newcommand*{\myauthor}{%
     \texorpdfstring{Alfredo Hernández \and John Smith}
       {Alfredo Hernández, John Smith}}
   ```

With the first solution, the authors in the metadata will be

> Alfredo Hernández and John Smith

With the second one you'll get

> Alfredo Hernández, John Smith

Of course, the second way is far more flexible.

Comment: Somehow, when I use the second approach (or use a comma in the first one) I get: 'Alfredo Hernández, John Smith';John Smith in the author metadata.
However, the first solution (using and) is exactly what I wanted.